# PHP 7 wampserver new use function error

Tags: php

So I've set my PHP version to 7 on WAMP and when I try to use this for example;

use {PDO, PDOException};

An error is returned saying the curly brackets are not supposed to be there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the curly brackets. This isn't valid syntax in any version of PHP: https://3v4l.org/tDpud

```
use PDO, PDOException;
```

[Group use declarations](http://php.net/manual/fr/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.group-use-declarations) (PHP 7.0 or newer) can only be used with namespaced classes.